# SH File not setting ENV variables (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, terminal, sh, bin

I have a file set_env.sh, that I run in the terminal using:

> sh set_env.sh

The code runs, but the variables are not set. I am checking with

> echo $EMAIL_SERVER

## set_env.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo email Address
read y

echo email password?
read x

export EMAIL_SERVER='smtp.gmail.com'
export EMAIL_PORT=587
export EMAIL_DOMAIN='domain.com'
export EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION='plain'
export EMAIL_ENABLE_STARTTLS_AUTO=true
export EMAIL_USERNAME=$y
export EMAIL_PASSWORD=$x
```

Comment: `source set_env.sh`?

Comment: That solved it. What's the difference between sh and source?

Comment: `sh set_env.sh` executes the script in separate shell context, in separate process, while `source` executes the script in the _current_ shell context. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `source` command instead:

```
source set_env.sh
```

The command executes the script in the *current shell context* as opposed to invocation via separate shell process: `sh set_env.sh` (the environment variables are set within the new `sh` process which is isolated from the current process).

---

By the way, you can use dot (`.`) instead of `source`, if you prefer.

Comment: does not works for me running from script in package.json file. Running directly the file in terminal works normal

Comment: @jose920405, it should work as long as the script is parsed by a shell compatible with the standard shell command language. So if a `package.json`  contains a command like `"./my-script.sh"` where `./my-script.sh` sources another script, then the environment variables are expected to be set only _within the `my-script.sh` context_. Any other commands in the `package.json` would not share the sourced environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your ~/.bash_profile file in your home dir with this

```
export EMAIL_SERVER='smtp.gmail.com'
export EMAIL_PORT=587
export EMAIL_DOMAIN='domain.com'
export EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION='plain'
export EMAIL_ENABLE_STARTTLS_AUTO=true
export EMAIL_USERNAME=$y
export EMAIL_PASSWORD=$x
```